# In a visual studio extension, how can I extract the body of the method that has focus?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I would like to be able to extract the body of the method that has focus.

So I would click anywhere in the method, then right click -> menu action, and I would be able to have the body of the focused method as a string or a list of string (lines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your extension is a package and not an add-in, first get the DTE instance as explained in:

[HOWTO: Get an EnvDTE.DTE instance from a Visual Studio package.](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/)

Then get the EnvDTE.CodeElement under the cursor:

[HOWTO: Get the code element at the cursor from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in.](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/)

Once you have the EnvDTE.CodeElement that represents the method, you call:

```
EnvDTE.EditPoint e1 = codeElement.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody).CreateEditPoint();

EnvDTE.EditPoint e2 = codeElement.GetEndPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody).CreateEditPoint();

string text = e1.GetText(e2);
```

That said, in VS 2015 and higher you can use the [.NET Compiler Platform ( "Roslyn")](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/documentation) to get that information